# Convert fraction part of hours into minutes using sql or c#

Tags: c#, sql

Is there any straight function that can convert fraction part of hours into minutes using sql or c# ?

For instance;
Input 4.5 hours and output 04:30(4 hours and 30 minutes).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

You could do this:

```
var mins = TimeSpan.FromHours(4.5).Minutes;
```

Note that "converting the fraction part of hours into minutes" is a totally separate concern from displaying timespans in a certain format. To get the `"04:30"` output you've mentioned in your question, you could do:

```
var fmtString = TimeSpan.FromHours(4.5).ToString(@"hh\:mm");
```

Comment: No idea, that's what answer I was about to post as well... Maybe you need something to format it to a string like "4:30"?

Comment: No you didn't.  You converted to a string.  To convert from fraction to minutes, simply multiply by 60.

Comment: @jdweng No I didn't what?

Comment: @jdweng Also, it looks like you've missed the first snippet in the answer. Your approach is wrong, because it will not convert only the fractional part of the hours provided to minutes. You would need to separate the fractional part from the provided double (using modulo or whatever) before multiplying by 60.

Comment: @asad Hey thanks for your answer but this is giving me error - Input string was not in a correct format. I have used it in my view as @TimeSpan.FromHours(4.5).ToString("hh:mm")

Comment: I know how to do it.  The question didn't ask to separate hours and minutes.  I wasn't trying to answer the question, just correct what you did.

Comment: @jdweng can you post the answer please ?

Comment: @jdweng The question did ask how to separate hours and minutes. That's what the "fraction part of hours" is. If you multiply 4.5 by 60, you get 270 minutes, which is not the fraction part of 4.5 hours (the correct answer is 30 minutes).

Comment: @Learner I forgot to escape the string. It's supposed to be `"hh\\:mm"`. I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Here I found function that Converts a decimal e.g. 4.5 to 4 hour 30 minutes**

```
/// <summary>Converts a decimal e.g. 1.5 to 1 hour 30 minutes</summary>
/// <param name="duration">The time to convert as a double</param>
/// <returns>
///     Returns a string in format:
///     x hours x minutes
///     x hours (if there's no minutes)
///     x minutes (if there's no hours)
///     Will also pluralise the words if required e.g. 1 hour or 3 hours
/// </returns>
public String convertDecimalToHoursMinutes(double time)
{
    TimeSpan timespan = TimeSpan.FromHours(time);
    int hours = timespan.Hours;
    int mins = timespan.Minutes;

    // Convert to hours and minutes
    String hourString = (hours > 0) ? string.Format("{0} " + pluraliseTime(hours, "hour"), hours) : "";
    String minString = (mins > 0) ? string.Format("{0} " + pluraliseTime(mins, "minute"), mins) : "";

    // Add a space between the hours and minutes if necessary
    return (hours > 0 && mins > 0) ? hourString + " " + minString : hourString + minString;
}

/// <summary>Pluralise hour or minutes based on the amount of time</summary>
/// <param name="num">The number of hours or minutes</param>
/// <param name="word">The word to pluralise e.g. "hour" or "minute"</param>
/// <returns> Returns correct English pluralisation e.g. 3 hours, 1 minute, 0 minutes</returns>
public String pluraliseTime(int num, String word)
{
    return (num == 0 || num > 1) ? word + "s" : word;
}
```